# how can you upload files to an Azure Web Apps virtual directory?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

how can you upload files to an Azure Web Apps virtual directory ?

I created a virtual directory for example called \UAT but when i log  on via ftp its not visible ?

[image]

Comment: afaik you can get publish settings via azure portal. That should contain what you need

Comment: Thanks i did that and it worked but when i ftp into the web app the virtual directory i created doesnt appear?

Comment: @itye1970 Please don't change your question. If we answered your question, you should accept it and start a new one.

Answer (score 24):

You can set the FTP credentials on the *Deployment credentials* blade within your App Service:

[image]

---

However, the easiest way is to upload your files using the **KUDU** console. To access the console navigate to `https://<yoursite>.scm.azurewebsites.net` where `<yoursite>` is the name of your App

In the Kudu console, click on the *Debug Console* tab, then on *PowerShell*. That will open a file browser where you can navigate to your directory and upload the files **by dragging and dropping the files into the browser window**:

[image]

Comment: The PowerShell file browser does accept drag-and-drop file upload, despite lack of visual feedback.

Comment: Just be aware that the Kudu container where you're uploading files is distinct from your website container.

Comment: thanks @Arash Motamedi
 drag and drop a great solution

Comment: In case you can't find the file Manager, it's here:
`https://<yourwebsite>.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui/fileManager`

Answer (score 21):

From the Kudu powershell console, if you open a folder in the file browser, you can drag and drop a zip file into it.  It's not obvious until you drag the file over top of the file explorer at which time a box opens up over the size column that says "Drag here to upload and unzip".

Comment: good tip, avoids setting up ftp access, and can still move a group of files, either in .zip archive or a regular file folder.

Comment: I was holding back on using this step because I was trying to upload a .db SQLite file. Then I realised, Kudu allows you drag and drop any file, and not just .zip. So, just go ahead and upload whatever file you want, with or without zip. it works.

Answer (score 14):

1. Go to YOURSITE.scm.azurewebsites.net/ZipDeployUI
2. Drag and drop
   [image]

**Note: all files and folders in current wwwroot will be removed without warning**

Comment: In my case, it was `YOURSITE.scm` instead of `YOURSITE`

Answer (score 4):

I used Visual Studio IDE. Access the Publish interface as shown below.

[image]

- Click ***Manage in Cloud Explorer*** it will open the specified Azure App web service. Drill down to ***Files>wwwroot*** and right click then select ***Upload File***

[image]

Hopefully it works for your case.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to App Service Editor

[image]

2. There you can manipulate files with right click context menu:
   [image]