# Possible to edit web.config of cloud app deployed on windows Azure without redeploying app?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I would like to add rewrite URL code on azure web app's web.config without redeploying the whole app again. for this I am using 'app service editor' and 'kudu- debug console' for editing the web.config, first I cant save the file and gives me error.
[image]

after some search I found that under APP SETTING KEY value should be 0 instead 1

[image]

edited the value 1 to 0 and save the APP SETTING KEY, after that I am able to edited the config file, in order to test the code again I changed the value 0 to 1 and save the setting. but when I refresh the file which is opened in editor or kudu the pasted code disappeared, the site is connected with automatic azure deployment pipeline

```
How I can edited the web.config file without redeploying the app again.
```

Comment: Would you consider using other deploy method like web deploy, zip deploy instead of `run from package`? It's possible to do what you want, but the workaround is a bit complex. So I think a redeployment would be better if you don't have specific reason to avoid redeploying... (PS: I'll post my detailed workaround later for you)

Comment: Details workaround updated, feel free to let me know if you meet any issue when trying my workaround. PS: 1. My workaround doesn't require any changes to the wwwroot, so we don't need to change the value of xxx to 0 to make wwwroot editable. 2.After all changes, you may need to restart the app service. (Not necessary, but recommended~)

Comment: Yes exactly workaround is bit strange and complex, so I would go the option-- deployment method 'WebDeploy' instead Zip Package in azure release pipeline task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's **possible** to make changes without redeploying the app.

**Some details:**

Check [Run the package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package#run-the-package) document and we can find:

1.The zip package won't be extracted to `D:\home\site\wwwroot`, instead it will be uploaded directly to `D:\home\data\SitePackages`.

2.A `packagename.txt` which contains the name of the ZIP package to load at runtime will be created in the same directory.

3.App Service mounts the uploaded package as the read-only wwwroot directory and runs the app directly from that mounted directory. (That's why we can't edit the read-only wwwroot directory directly)

**So my workaround is:**

1.Navigate to `D:\home\data\SitePackages` in via `kudu- debug console`:

[image]

Download the zip(In my case it's `20200929072235.zip`) which represents your deployed app, extract this zip file and do some changes to `web.config` file.

[image]

2.Zip those files(choose those files and right-click...) into a `childtest.zip`, please follow my steps carefully here!!! The folder structure of Run-from-package is a bit strange!!!

[image]

3.Then zip the `childtest.zip` into `parenttest.zip`(When uploading the xx.zip, the kudu always automatically extra them. So we have to zip the `childtest.zip` into `parenttest.zip` first)

[image]

4.[Drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59396598/10910450) local `parenttest.zip` into online `SitePackages` folder in `kudu-debug console` and we can get a `childtest.zip` now:

[image]

5.Modify the `packagename.txt`, change the content from `20200929072235.zip` to `childtest.zip` and **Save**:

[image]

**Done**~

**Check and test:**

Now let's open `App Service Editor` to check the changes:

[image]

**In addition:** Though it answers the original question, I recommend using other deployment methods(web deploy...) as a workaround. It could be much easier~

Comment: Well explained. :-)