# Azure Devops Release Pipeline - Deploy single file to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a single file that I need to deploy to an existing App Service (that already contains an application, deployed previously through another pipeline).

I would like to avoid using the FTP task for that.

Is there a way to deploy a single file to a specific folder in an App Service via a DevOps Pipeline?

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: No because this will copy a file on the build server. What I want is to copy the file to the App Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually FTP seems to be the easiest way to deploy single file. However if you don't want to use it you can use [KUDU API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#vfs). What you need is to wrap it in powershell script:

```bsh
$username = '$(username)'
$password = '$(password)'
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))

$apiUrl = "https://$(siteName).scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/your-file"
$filePath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/your-file"
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo))
$headers.Add("If-Match", "*")

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $headers -Method PUT -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

Here you find info how to get [credentials](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials#user-credentials-aka-deployment-credentials).

But if this is one time task you may use drag & drop from KUDU panel as it is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628367/how-can-you-upload-files-to-an-azure-web-apps-virtual-directory)